# Getting itemattachments from messsages in graphapi

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am working in .NET and trying to get a calendar invite within a message. When I do this query :

```
_client.Users.me.Messages["aaa..."].Attachments.Request().GetAsync()
```

The result does not have the invite in the list of attachments.

If I call

```
_client.Users.me.Messages["aaa..."].Request().Expand("attachments").GetAsync()
```

I still get no attachments except the invite information is in in AdditionalData collection

I have no idea how to get the attachment into the attachment list and every tutorial and code snippet I have seen have told me to access the attachment directly using the `.Attachments["ID"]` but I don't have the ID so can't access it.

Anyone else having a similar problem?

Comment: I tried the following steps with Microsoft Graph explorer: (1) This give the attachment (the calendar as attachment) https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkAGRlNWM4Njk4LWY3NTYtNGE/attachments/AAMkAGRlNWM4Njk4LWY3NTYtNGE2MC05ZjQzLTg1YmM5YjIzNTRhMwBGAAAAAAA-/ (1) This give the attachment's value https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkAGRlNWM4Njk4LWY3NTYtNGE/attachments/AAMkAGRlNWM4Njk4LWY3NTYtNGE2MC05ZjQzLTg1YmM5YjIzNTRhMwBGAAAAAAA-/$value

Comment: The equivalent .net sdk code would be (to get the content, from the attachments)

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var stream = await graphClient.Me.Messages["AAMkAGRlNWM4Njk4LWY3NTYtNGE2MC05ZjQzLTg1Y"].Attachments["AAMkAGRlNWM4Njk4LWY3NTYtNGE2MC05ZjQzLTg1YmM5YjIzNTRh"].Content
 .Request()
 .GetAsync();